# Using axious patch to edit a user profile in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, axios

I'm trying to use Axious to give user the possibility to edit their user. I am using JSON file to store user information.

I need help to write my API, so it updates the currentusers user information in the JSON-file.
The user that is logged in is saved in local storage under currentUser.

Here is my code in editUser.js

```
function updateFunction() {
  let updateData = {
      username : localStorage.getItem('currentUser'),
      age: age.value,
      description: description.value,
      email: email.value,
      phone: phone.value,
      city: city.value,
      zip: zip.value,
      address: address.value,
      password : password.value, 
  }

   axios.patch("http://localhost:2500/editProfile/" +usernameCurent, updateData)
          .then(function(response){
          console.log(response);

          } 

      .then(() => window.location = "../view/userProfile.html"));
```

}

Here is my code in API.js

```
app.patch('/editProfile/:username', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile(dataPath, "utf8", (err, data) => {
        let parsedData = JSON.parse(data)
        const username = req.params["username"];
        console.log(data)
        parsedData[username] = req.body;
        fs.writeFile(dataPath, JSON.stringify(parsedData), () => {
            res.status(200).send('${username} updated');
        })
    })
})
```

I need help to write the API so it updates storage.JSON where all the users are stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the spread operator (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) will allow you to take the current and join it with your new data, something like:

```js
app.patch('/editProfile/:username', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile(dataPath, "utf8", (err, data) => {
        let parsedData = JSON.parse(data)
        const username = req.params["username"];
        console.log(data)

        // this will use the current user, and only update those fields 
        // which are sent in the request body. If only one field is sent, 
        // only that field will be updated.
        const updatedUser = {...parsedData[username], ...req.body}         

        // we then set the parsedData to the new patched user.
        parsedData[username] = updatedUser 

        fs.writeFile(dataPath, JSON.stringify(parsedData), () => {
            res.status(200).send('${username} updated');
        })
    })
})
```